# replace text between two tabs - sed

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have the following input files:

```
text1 text2 text3 text4
abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4
```

and I am trying to find the second string between the two tabs (e.g. text2, abc2) and replace it with another word.

I have tried with

```
sed s'/\t*\t/sample/1'
```

but it only deletes the tab and does not replace the word.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information (and a badge :) ).  Please upvote any answers you find useful, and hit the checkmark on the one you finally use to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using awk here:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { $2 = "sample" } 1' file
```

Set the input and output field separators to a tab and change the second field. The `1` at the end is always true, so awk does the default action, `{ print }`.

Comment: Great minds think alike --- and only 13 seconds apart :)

Comment: Or, `awk -v OFS='\t' '$2="sample"'`

Comment: I ended up using this option, as it allows me to change to other columns more practically. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @karakfa it's very compact but I don't really like relying on the RHS of the assignment being "true". This would break for `""`, `0` or even `"0"`...I guess the input field separator doesn't need changing but this handles spaces within fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed 's/\t[^\t]*\t/\tsample\t/'
```

Comment: Yes.  The OP may be misinterpreting the `*` operator as a shell-globbing operator – ie, ‘match anything’ – as opposed to its actual meaning in a (sed or other) regular expression.  The OP's original pattern, `\t*\t` means ‘match zero or more tabs followed by a tab’, and so will indeed delete only the first sequence of tabs that it comes to.

Comment: sat, this works for four columns but replaces both the second and fourth if there is a 5th column.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative in gawk, since you tagged `awk` ---

```
 gawk -- 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} {$2="sample"; print}'
```

For example,

```
 echo -e 'a\tb\tc\td' | gawk -- 'BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"} {$2="sample"; print}'
```

prints

```
a    sample  c      d
```

The `FS` breaks input at tabs, `OFS` separates output fields using tabs, and `$2="sample"` changes only the second field, leaving the rest of the fields unchanged.

Comment: fyi there's nothing gawk-specific about that, it'll work in any awk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\) \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\) \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\) \([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)/\1 sample \2 \3 \4/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU sed v4.2.2 I had to use `-r`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t)[^\t]*/\1sample/'
```

The `^([^\t]*\t)` is the first field and the first tab, and the `[^\t]*` is the text of the second field.  The `\1` restores the first field and the `sample` is whatever you want :) .

For example,

```
echo -e 'a\tb\tc\td' | sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t)[^\t]*/\1sample/'
```

prints

```
a       sample  c       d
```

This also works for other than four columnns.  For example

```
$ echo -e 'a\tb\tc' | sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t)[^\t]*/\1sample/'
a       sample  c

$ echo -e 'a\tb\tc\td\te' | sed -r 's/^([^\t]*\t)[^\t]*/\1sample/'
a       sample  c       d       e
```